# public class PeripheralManager - returning all stubs

Tags: android, android-things

I have imported
`implementation 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'`

And when I execute code, it throws a runtime error because inside of the PeripheralManager class the methods are all stubs:

```
    public List<String> getUartDeviceList() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
```

This was working several months ago, I've tried changing `implementation` to `compile`

Comment: Did you managed to pass this issue? Because i have it too

Answer (score 1):

There are several conditions you should verify in your project:

- Your device **must be** either the i.MX7D or Raspberry Pi 3B with the Android Things OS on it, as [noted in the hardware guide](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware).
- Your `app/build.gradle` must use `compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'`
- Your `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` must include the following as a child of the `application` element:

```xml
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things"/>
```

You may also want to check properties like the `targetSdkVersion` being `27`. If you continue to run into trouble, check out [Android Things sample projects](https://github.com/androidthings/doorbell).

Comment: Thank you!  It was working before w/ the raspberry pi 4 earlier this year, but I also had a UART device connected before.  Will I need the peripheral connected to resolve..?

Comment: It won't matter if a peripheral is connected or not, you need to have the right library on the device, which won't exist on a Raspberry Pi 4 as Android Things isn't supported on that board. Without this library, the app will not compile. In theory one could port the library, but that would be unofficial.

Answer (score 0):

Which device are you running it into? This API is only available on Android Things boards, not on phones.

Comment: It's for Raspberry Pi 4

Comment: Then your out of luck, only Raspberry pi 3+ was supported on Android Things (and the pico board too)